# Conflict with ruby and nginx on my production server?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, production-environment

I have a weird problem on my production server. There are Ubuntu server, nginx + phusion passenger installed on it. I manage my ruby version with rvm and it's ruby 1.9.3-p327 and rails 3.2.9.

Sometimes, it's impossible to deploy my app because the `rake asset:precompile` task failed. When I try to execute this directly on my server I have the same problem. Same trace when I run `bundle exec rails c production`

Here a part (the end) of the trace (I'm sorry, I don't have the complete trace because it's too long):

```
3.2.0/lib/paperclip.rb
 966 /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ancestry-1.3.0/lib/ancestry/class_methods.rb
 967 /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ancestry-1.3.0/lib/ancestry/instance_methods.rb
 968 /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/ancestry-1.3.0/lib/ancestry/exceptions.rb

 * Process memory map:

 00400000-00401000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50595451                           /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
 00600000-00601000 r--p 00000000 09:02 50595451                           /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
 00601000-00602000 rw-p 00001000 09:02 50595451                           /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/bin/ruby
 00602000-037a4000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                                  [heap]
 7f19e615d000-7f19e615e000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f19e615e000-7f19e6188000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594719                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
 7f19e6188000-7f19e6387000 ---p 0002a000 09:02 50594719                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
 7f19e6387000-7f19e6388000 r--p 00029000 09:02 50594719                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
 7f19e6388000-7f19e6389000 rw-p 0002a000 09:02 50594719                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.
 9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/socket.so
 7f19e6389000-7f19e638e000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594729                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
 7f19e638e000-7f19e658d000 ---p 00005000 09:02 50594729                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
 7f19e658d000-7f19e658e000 r--p 00004000 09:02 50594729                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/li
 b/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
 7f19e658e000-7f19e658f000 rw-p 00005000 09:02 50594729                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/racc/cparse.so
 7f19e658f000-7f19e6590000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594733                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
 7f19e6590000-7f19e678f000 ---p 00001000 09:02 50594733                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
 7f19e678f000-7f19e6790000 r--p 00000000 09:02 50594733                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
 7f19e6790000-7f19e6791000 rw-p 00001000 09:02 50594733                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/md5.so
 7f19e6791000-7f19e67d1000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f19e67d1000-7f19e67d2000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0

 7f1a0b2e9000-7f1a0b2ea000 r--p 00014000 09:01 132081                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
 7f1a0b2ea000-7f1a0b2eb000 rw-p 00015000 09:01 132081                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1
 7f1a0b2eb000-7f1a0b3cd000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 399334                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
 7f1a0b3cd000-7f1a0b5cc000 ---p 000e2000 09:01 399334                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
 7f1a0b5cc000-7f1a0b5d4000 r--p 000e1000 09:01 399334                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
 7f1a0b5d4000-7f1a0b5d6000 rw-p 000e9000 09:01 399334                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.16
 7f1a0b5d6000-7f1a0b5eb000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a0b5eb000-7f1a0b988000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50987342                   /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2/ext/v8/v8.so
 7f1a0b988000-7f1a0bb88000 ---p 0039d000 09:02 50987342                   /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2/ext/v8/v8.so
 7f1a0bb88000-7f1a0bbab000 r--p 0039d000 09:02 50987342                   /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2/ext/v8/v8.so
 7f1a0bbab000-7f1a0bbaf000 rw-p 003c0000 09:02 50987342                   /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/therubyracer-0.10.2/ext/v8/v8.so
 7f1a0bbaf000-7f1a0bbb2000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a0bbb2000-7f1a0bc50000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 398982                     /usr/lib/x86_64-
 7f1a0be9a000-7f1a0c09a000 ---p 00045000 09:01 399309                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
 7f1a0c09a000-7f1a0c09c000 r--p 00045000 09:01 399309                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
 7f1a0c09c000-7f1a0c09e000 rw-p 00047000 09:01 399309                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhx509.so.5.0.0
 7f1a0c09e000-7f1a0c09f000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a0c4d6000-7f1a0c4d7000 rw-p 00028000 09:01 399337                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwind.so.0.0.0
 7f1a0c4d7000-7f1a0c4da000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132084                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
 7f1a0c4da000-7f1a0c6d9000 ---p 00003000 09:01 132084                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
 7f1a0c6d9000-7f1a0c6da000 r--p 00002000 09:01 132084                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
 7f1a0c6da000-7f1a0c6db000 rw-p 00003000 09:01 132084                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0.8.0
 7f1a0c6db000-7f1a0c6ec000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 399321                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
 7f1a0c6ec000-7f1a0c8eb000 ---p 00011000 09:01 399321                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
 7f1a0c8eb000-7f1a0c8ec000 r--p 00010000 09:01 399321                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
 7f1a0c8ec000-7f1a0c8ed000 rw-p 00011000 09:01 399321                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libp11-kit.so.0.0.0
 7f1a0c8ed000-7f1a0c8fd000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 403677                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.12
 7f1a0c8fd000-7f1a0cafc000 ---p 00010000 09:01 403677                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.12
 7f1a0cafc000-7f1a0cafd000 r--p 0000f000 09:01 403677                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.12
 7f1a0cafd000-7f1a0cafe000 rw-p 00010000 09:01 403677                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libtasn1.so.3.1.12
 7f1a0cafe000-7f1a0cb12000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 399329                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
 7f1a0cb12000-7f1a0cd11000 ---p 00014000 09:01 399329                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
 7f1a0cd11000-7f1a0cd12000 r--p 00013000 09:01 399329                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libroken.so.18.1.0
 7f1a0cf45000-7f1a0cf46000 rw-p 00032000 09:01 399306                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libhcrypto.so.4.1.0
 7f1a0cf46000-7f1a0cf47000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a0cf47000-7f1a0cfe2000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 399279                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
 7f1a0cfe2000-7f1a0d1e1000 ---p 0009b000 09:01 399279                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
 7f1a0d1e1000-7f1a0d1e3000 r--p 0009a000 09:01 399279                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
 7f1a0d1e3000-7f1a0d1e7000 rw-p 0009c000 09:01 399279                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasn1.so.8.0.0
 7f1a0d1e7000-7f1a0d267000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 399312                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
 7f1a0d267000-7f1a0d467000 ---p 00080000 09:01 399312                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
 7f1a0d467000-7f1a0d469000 r--p 00080000 09:01 399312                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/lib
 krb5.so.26.0.0
 7f1a0d469000-7f1a0d46d000 rw-p 00082000 09:01 399312                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.26.0.0
 7f1a0d46d000-7f1a0d473000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 399308                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
 7f1a0d473000-7f1a0d672000 ---p 00006000 09:01 399308                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
 7f1a0d672000-7f1a0d673000 r--p 00005000 09:01 399308                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
 7f1a0d673000-7f1a0d674000 rw-p 00006000 09:01 399308                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libheimntlm.so.0.1.0
 7f1a0d674000-7f1a0d6ee000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 131966                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
 7f1a0d6ee000-7f1a0d8ee000 ---p 0007a000 09:01 131966                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
 7f1a0d8ee000-7f1a0d8ef000 r--p 0007a000 09:01 131966                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
 7f1a0d8ef000-7f1a0d8f2000 rw-p 0007b000 09:01 131966                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.11.7.0
 7f1a0d8f2000-7f1a0d9a6000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 398964                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.21.8
 7f1a0d9a6000-7f1a0dba6000 ---p 000b4000 09:01 398964                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.21.8
 7f1a0dba6000-7f1a0dbac000 r--p 000b4000 09:01 398964                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.21.8
 7f1a0dbac000-7f1a0dbad000 rw-p 000ba000 09:01 398964                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgnutls.so.26.21.8
 7f1a0dbad000-7f1a0dbae000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a0dbae000-7f1a0dbe8000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 399303                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi.so.3.0.0
 7f1a0dbe8000-7f1a0dde8000 ---p 0003a000 09:01 399303                     /usr/lib/x86_64-
 7f1a0e213000-7f1a0e214000 r--p 0000c000 09:01 403690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.8.1
 7f1a0e214000-7f1a0e215000 rw-p 0000d000 09:01 403690                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblber-2.4.so.2.8.1
 7f1a0e215000-7f1a0e22d000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132255                     /lib/x86_64-
 7f1a0eeef000-7f1a0eef0000 r--p 0003b000 09:01 398940                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
 7f1a0eef0000-7f1a0eef2000 rw-p 0003c000 09:01 398940                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgssapi_krb5.so.2.2
 7f1a0eef2000-7f1a0eef5000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132073                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
 7f1a0eef5000-7f1a0f0f4000 ---p 00003000 09:01 132073                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc
 om_err.so.2.1
 7f1a0f0f4000-7f1a0f0f5000 r--p 00002000 09:01 132073                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
 7f1a0f0f5000-7f1a0f0f6000 rw-p 00003000 09:01 132073                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcom_err.so.2.1
 7f1a0f0f6000-7f1a0f1ba000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 398933                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
 7f1a0f1ba000-7f1a0f3b9000 ---p 000c4000 09:01 398933                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
 7f1a0f3b9000-7f1a0f3c3000 r--p 000c3000 09:01 398933                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
 7f1a0f3c3000-7f1a0f3c4000 rw-p 000cd000 09:01 398933                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libkrb5.so.3.3
 7f1a0f3c4000-7f1a0f3ed000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 408194                     /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4
 7f1a0f3ed000-7f1a0f5ec000 ---p 00029000 09:01 408194                     /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4
 7f1a0f5ec000-7f1a0f5ee000 r--p 00028000 09:01 408194                     /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4
 7f1a0f5ee000-7f1a0f5f0000 rw-p 0002a000 09:01 408194                     /usr/lib/libpq.so.5.4
 7f1a0f5f0000-7f1a0f601000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50728854                   /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.so
 7f1a0f601000-7f1a0f801000 ---p 00011000 09:02 50728854                   /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.so
 7f1a0f801000-7f1a0f802000 r--p 00011000 09:02 50728854                   /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.so
 7f1a
 0f802000-7f1a0f803000 rw-p 00012000 09:02 50728854                   /home/deploy/www/limouzi/shared/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/pg-0.14.1/lib/pg_ext.so
 7f1a0f803000-7f1a0f816000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594709                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
 7f1a0f816000-7f1a0fa15000 ---p 00013000 09:02 50594709                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
 7f1a0fa15000-7f1a0fa16000 r--p 00012000 09:02 50594709                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
 7f1a0fa16000-7f1a0fa17000 rw-p 00013000 09:02 50594709                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/bigdecimal.so
 7f1a0fa17000-7f1a0fa18000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594712                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
 7f1a0fa18000-7f1a0fc17000 ---p 00001000 09:02 50594712                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/rub
 y-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
 7f1a0fc17000-7f1a0fc18000 r--p 00000000 09:02 50594712                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
 7f1a0fc18000-7f1a0fc19000 rw-p 00001000 09:02 50594712                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/fcntl.so
 7f1a0fc19000-7f1a0fc6b000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 131958                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
 7f1a0fc6b000-7f1a0fe6b000 ---p 00052000 09:01 131958                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
 7f1a0fe6b000-7f1a0fe6e000 r--p 00052000 09:01 131958                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
 7f1a0fe6e000-7f1a0fe74000 rw-p 00055000 09:01 131958                     /lib/x86_6
 4-linux-gnu/libssl.so.1.0.0
 7f1a0fe74000-7f1a0fe75000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a0fe75000-7f1a0fecc000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594724                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
 7f1a0fecc000-7f1a100cc000
 ---p 00057000 09:02 50594724                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
 7f1a100cc000-7f1a100cd000 r--p 00057000 09:02 50594724                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
 7f1a100cd000-7f1a100cf000 rw-p 00058000 09:02 50594724                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/openssl.so
 7f1a100cf000-7f1a100d0000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a100d0000-7f1a100df000 r-xp
 00000000 09:02 50594723                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
 7f1a100df000-7f1a102de000 ---p 0000f000 09:02 50594723                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
 7f1a102de000-7f1a102df000 r--p 0000e000 09:02 50594723                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
 7f1a102df000-7f1a102e0000 rw-p 0000f000 09:02 50594723                   /home/deploy/.rvm/r
 ubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/zlib.so
 7f1a102e0000-7f1a102e2000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594806                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
 7f1a102e2000-7f1a104e1000 ---p 00002000 09:02 50594806                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
 7f1a104e1000-7f1a104e2000 r--p 00001000 09:02 50594806                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
 7f1a104e2000-7f1a104e3000 rw-p 00002000 09:02 50594806                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/iso_8859_1.so
 7f1a104e3000-7f1a104e6000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594833
 /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest.so
 7f1a104e6000-7f1a106e5000 ---p 00003000 09:02 50594833                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest.so
 7f1a106e5000-7f1a106e6
 000 r--p 00002000 09:02 50594833                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest.so
 7f1a106e6000-7f1a106e7000 rw-p 00003000 09:02 50594833                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest.so
 7f1a106e7000-7f1a106fd000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132127                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
 7f1a106fd000-7f1a108fc000 ---p 00016000 09:01 132127                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
 7f1a108fc000-7f1a108fd000 r--p 00015000 09:01 132127                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
 7f1a108fd000-7f1a108fe000 rw-p 00016000 09:01 132127                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1.2.3.4
 7f1a108fe000-7f1a10a9d000 r-xp 00000000 09
 :01 131959                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
 7f1a10a9d000-7f1a10c9c000 ---p 0019f000 09:01 131959                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
 7f1a10c9c000-7f1a10cb7000 r--p 0019e000 09:01 131959
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
 7f1a10cb7000-7f1a10cc2000 rw-p 001b9000 09:01 131959                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
 7f1a10cc2000-7f1a10cc6000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a10cc6000-7f1a10cc7000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594731                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so
 7f1a10cc7000-7f1a10ec6000 ---p 00001000 09:02 50594731                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest
 /sha1.so
 7f1a10ec6000-7f1a10ec7000 r--p 00000000 09:02 50594731                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so
 7f1a10ec7000-7f1a10ec8000 rw-p 00001000 09:02 50594731                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/digest/sha1.so
 7f1a10ec8000-7f1a10efa000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594827                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
 7f1a10efa000-7f1a110fa000 ---p 000
 32000 09:02 50594827                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
 7f1a110fa000-7f1a110fb000 r--p 00032000 09:02 50594827                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
 7f1a110fb000-7f1a110fd000 rw-p 00033000 09:02 50594827                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/date_core.so
 7f1a110fd000-7f1a110fe000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a110fe000-7f1a11104000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594828                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
 7f1a11104000-7f1a11303000 ---p 00006000 09:02 50594828                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64
 -linux/strscan.so
 7f1a11303000-7f1a11304000 r--p 00005000 09:02 50594828                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
 7f1a11304000-7f1a11305000 rw-p 00006000 09:02 50594828                   /home/deploy
 /.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/strscan.so
 7f1a11305000-7f1a1130c000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594711                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
 7f1a1130c000-7f1a1150b000 ---p 00007000 09:02 50594711                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
 7f1a1150b000-7f1a1150c000 r--p 00006000 09:02 50594711                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-
 linux/stringio.so
 7f1a1150c000-7f1a1150d000 rw-p 00007000 09:02 50594711                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/stringio.so
 7f1a1150d000-7f1a1152d000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50467319                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/libyaml-0.so.2.0.2
 7f1a1152d000-7f1a1172c000 ---p 00020000 09:02 50467319                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/libyaml-0.so.2.0.2
 7f1a1172c000-7f1a1172d000 r--p 0001f000 09:02 50467319
 /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/libyaml-0.so.2.0.2
 7f1a1172d000-7f1a1172e000 rw-p 00020000 09:02 50467319                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/libyaml-0.so.2.0.2
 7f1a1172e000-7f1a11735000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594746                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/psych.so
 7f1a11735000-7f1a11934000 ---p 00007000 09:02 50594746                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/psych.so
 7f
 1a11934000-7f1a11935000 r--p 00006000 09:02 50594746                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/psych.so
 7f1a11935000-7f1a11936000 rw-p 00007000 09:02 50594746                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/psych.so
 7f1a11936000-7f1a11939000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594736                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/etc.so
 7f1a11939000-7f1a11b38000 ---p 00003000 09:02 50594736
 /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/etc.so
 7f1a11b38000-7f1a11b39000 r--p 00002000 09:02 50594736                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/etc.so
 7f1a11b39000-7f1a11b3a000 rw-p 00003000 09:02 50594736                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/etc.so
 7f1a11b3a000-7f1a11b40000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594832                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
 7f1a11b40000-7f1a11d40000 ---p 00006000 09:02 50594832                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
 7f1a11d40000-7f1a11d41000 r--p 00006000 09:02 50594832                   /ho
 me/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
 7f1a11d41000-7f1a11d42000 rw-p 00007000 09:02 50594832                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/pathname.so
 7f1a11d42000-7f1a11d4400
 0 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594801                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
 7f1a11d44000-7f1a11f44000 ---p 00002000 09:02 50594801                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
 7f1a11f44000-7f1a11f45000 r--p 00002000 09:02 50594801                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
 7f1a11f45000-7f1a11f46000 rw-p 00003000 09:02 50594801                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/trans/transdb.so
 7f1a11f46000-7f1a11f48000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50594756                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linu
 x/enc/encdb.so
 7f1a11f48000-7f1a12147000 ---p 00002000 09:02 50594756                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
 7f1a12147000-7f1a12148000 r--p 00001000 09:02 50594756                   /home/deploy/
 .rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
 7f1a12148000-7f1a12149000 rw-p 00002000 09:02 50594756                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/ruby/1.9.1/x86_64-linux/enc/encdb.so
 7f1a12149000-7f1a1234c000 r--p 00000000 09:01 394409                     /usr/lib/locale/locale-archive
 7f1a1234c000-7f1a12447000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132258                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
 7f1a12447000-7f1a12646000 ---p 000fb000 09:01 132258                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
 7f1a12646000-7f1a12647000 r--p 000fa000 09:01 132258                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
 7f1a12647000-7f1a12648000 rw-p 000fb000 09:01 132258                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.15.so
 7f1a1264
 8000-7f1a12651000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132259                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.15.so
 7f1a12651000-7f1a12851000 ---p 00009000 09:01 132259                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.15.so
 7f1a12851000-7f1a12852000 r--p 00009000
 09:01 132259                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypt-2.15.so
 7f1a12a85000-7f1a12a8c000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132254                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libr
 t-2.15.so
 7f1a12a8c000-7f1a12c8b000 ---p 00007000 09:01 132254                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
 7f1a12c8b000-7f1a12c8c000 r--p 00006000 09:01 132254                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
 7f1a12c8c000-7f1a12c8d000 rw
 -p 00007000 09:01 132254                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt-2.15.so
 7f1a12c8d000-7f1a12ca5000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132252                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
 7f1a12ca5000-7f1a12ea4000 ---p 00018000 09:01 132252                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
 7f1a12ea4000-7f1a12ea5000 r--p 00017000 09:01 132252                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
 7f1a12ea5000-7f1a12ea6000 rw-p 00018000 09:01 132252                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.15.so
 7f1a12ea6000-7f1a12eaa000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a12eaa000-7f1a1305f000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132250                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
 7f1a1305f000-7f1a1325e000 ---p 001b5000 09:01 132250                     /
 lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
 7f1a1325e000-7f1a13262000 r--p 001b4000 09:01 132250                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
 7f1a13262000-7f1a13264000 rw-p 001b8000 09:01 132250                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.15.so
 7f1a13
 264000-7f1a13269000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a13269000-7f1a134a7000 r-xp 00000000 09:02 50467318                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/libruby.so.1.9.1
 7f1a134a7000-7f1a136a6000 ---p 0023e000 09:02 50467318                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/libruby.so.1.9.1
 7f1a136a6000-7f1a136ab000 r--p 0023d000 09:02 50467318                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/libruby.so.1.9.1
 7f1a136ab000-7f1a136af000 rw-p 00242000 09:02 50467318                   /home/deploy/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p286/lib/libruby.so.1.9.1
 7f1a136af000-7f1a136cd000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a136cd000-7f1a136ef000 r-xp 00000000 09:01 132264                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
 7f1a13718000-7f1a137d8000 rw-p
 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a137d8000-7f1a137df000 r--s 00000000 09:01 400807                     /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/gconv/gconv-modules.cache
 7f1a137df000-7f1a138e5000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a138e9000-7f1a138ea000 ---p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a138ea000-7
 f1a138ef000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0
 7f1a138ef000-7f1a138f0000 r--p 00022000 09:01 132264                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
 7f1a138f0000-7f1a138f2000 rw-p 00023000 09:01 132264                     /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ld-2.15.so
 7fffa4851000-7fffa4872000 rw-p 00000000 00:00 0                          [stack]
 7fffa494e000-7fffa494f000 r-xp 00000000 00:00 0                          [vdso]
 ffffffffff600000-ffffffffff601000 r--p 00000000 00:00 0                  [vsyscall]


 [NOTE]
 You may have encountered a bug in the Ruby interpreter or extension libraries.
 Bug reports are welcome.
 For details: http://www.ruby-lang.org/bugreport.html
```

What is interesting is the end of the trace, which said there is a bug in the ruby interpreter. One time I have the beginning of the trace and It said something like this: `*** glibc detected *** ruby: double free or corruption (!prev)`

For the moment to fix the bug I need to restart nginx. It's for this reason I ask this question: Is it a conflict between ruby and nginx or inside ruby interpreter? And how to solve this?

Thanks

**Edit :**

Error already appear. I wonder if it's not a problem due to ImageMagick. Indeed a cron task execute some times by a day an upload of pictures. When there are not lot of pictures everything seems to be fine. But when there is about 100 pictures every two hours I have the feeling that the error appear. I will inspect this way. If somebody have an idea...

Comment: Have you tried upgrading to the latest 1.9.3 release? (p327 as of this writing)

Comment: I already upgraded ruby to 1.9.3-p327 my rvm ruby version but indeed it seems to still call the 1.9.3-p298 version. I did a hard reboot to solve this. For the moment the bug doesn't appear anymore but I will wait some time.

Comment: @RyanBigg The problem don't seems to appear anymore. I think I needed to reboot the server to use the last version of ruby, and this version seems to solve the error. If you want to write your response like an answer I will valid it.

Comment: Error still appear, see my edition.

Answer (score 1):

Try, export MALLOC_CHECK_=2. Because of this glibc will do  extra level of checking during free(), to avoid heap corruption. It will abort() and give a core dump as soon as it detects corruption, instead of waiting until there's an actual problem caused by the corruption.

or  use http://valgrind.org/ for more details.

Comment: It doesn't seem to work. I will try to find something with valgrind.